# java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation. Getting this while reading data from database and writing in a xls file

Tags: java, odbc

While running I'm getting below error

> java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation.     Getting this while reading data from database and writing in a xls file.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); // creating a workbook

HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("non_unified"); // creating sheet in workbook named non_unified
HSSFRow row=spreadsheet.createRow(0);  // creating rows
HSSFCell cell;   // creating cells of each row
  cell=row.createCell((short) 0);
  cell.setCellValue("AIRLINE");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 1);
  cell.setCellValue("CLASS_CODE");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 2);
  cell.setCellValue("CLASS_NAME");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 3);
  cell.setCellValue("MEAL_TYPE");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 4);
  cell.setCellValue("MEAL_TYPE_NAME");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 5);
  cell.setCellValue("SPML_CODE");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 6);
  cell.setCellValue("SPML_NAME");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 7);
  cell.setCellValue("SPML_SUBCODE_CODE");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 8);
  cell.setCellValue("SPML_SUBCODE_NAME");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 9);
  cell.setCellValue("MATERIAL_NBR");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 10);
  cell.setCellValue("MATERIAL_NAME");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 11);
  cell.setCellValue("EFF_DATE");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 12);
  cell.setCellValue("EXP_DATE");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 13);
  cell.setCellValue("SERVICE_LEVEL");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 14);
  cell.setCellValue("CYCLE_NO");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 15);
  cell.setCellValue("HAULAGE_CODE");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 16);
  cell.setCellValue("SALES_ORG_CODE");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 17);
  cell.setCellValue("PLANT_CODE");
  cell=row.createCell((short) 18);
  cell.setCellValue("SPML_ASSIGNMENT");


ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from V_SPML_ASSIGNMENT ");


int i=1;
while(rs.next()){    // setting value of each cell using database
  HSSFRow rows=   spreadsheet.createRow((short)i);
  rows.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("AIRLINE"));
  rows.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("CLASS_CODE"));
  rows.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString("CLASS_NAME"));
  rows.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getInt("MEAL_TYPE"));
  rows.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getString("MEAL_TYPE_NAME"));
  rows.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(rs.getString("SPML_CODE"));
  rows.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue(rs.getString("SPML_NAME"));
  rows.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue(rs.getString("SPML_SUBCODE_CODE"));
  rows.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue(rs.getInt("SPML_SUBCODE_NAME"));
  rows.createCell((short) 9).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("MATERIAL_NBR")));
  rows.createCell((short) 10).setCellValue(rs.getString("MATERIAL_NAME"));
  rows.createCell((short) 11).setCellValue(rs.getString("EFF_DATE"));
  rows.createCell((short) 12).setCellValue(rs.getString("EXP_DATE"));
  rows.createCell((short) 13).setCellValue(rs.getInt("SERVICE_LEVEL"));
  rows.createCell((short) 14).setCellValue(rs.getString("CYCLE_NO"));
  rows.createCell((short) 15).setCellValue(rs.getString("HAULAGE_CODE"));
  rows.createCell((short) 16).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("SALES_ORG_CODE")));
  rows.createCell((short) 17).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("PLANT_CODE")));
  rows.createCell((short) 18).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("SPML_ASSIGNMENT")));

  i++;
}

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:/Spml/exceldatabase.xls"));                // creating a file to store
workbook.write(out);        //writing into file
```

Comment: What are you getting on the stack trace?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation